# Exclude null results on a UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, which gives me the provider for a given title:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(provider) FROM 
    (SELECT title, provider FROM financials_raw 
        UNION 
        SELECT title, provider from sales_raw
    ) combined 
        WHERE title = 'Home'
```

However, this will return NULL provider results as well, how would I exclude all null results?

Comment: `WHERE title = 'Home' AND provider IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: Yeah, and drop the parenthesis, `distinct(x)` is the same as `distinct x`

Comment: Thanks, I was forgetting the `IS`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Further to my comment above, the following query will accomplish the same but be more efficient (as undesirable records are not first being joined in the `UNION` operation before subsequently being filtered from the materialised table):

```
  SELECT provider FROM financials_raw WHERE title = 'Home' AND provider IS NOT NULL
UNION
  SELECT provider FROM      sales_raw WHERE title = 'Home' AND provider IS NOT NULL
```

Note that `UNION` (without the `ALL` qualification) implies `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why this query is more efficient than the one above?

Comment: @David542: **as undesirable records are not first being joined in the `UNION` operation before subsequently being filtered from the materialised table**